Exterior Attic Walls
We noticed the tar paper/vapor barrier in our attic had mold on it, so we took it all off and threw it away to make sure there was no mold underneath. Once we pulled the tar paper back there was no mold, but the only thing there is the backside of our hardy plank siding. Shouldn’t there be a press board or something more solid that the hardy plank is attached to?

I would think so (there should be something more substantial behind the Hardi plank), but I don't know for certain.  You might want to visit the James Hardi web site to see what they recommend for installation.

It may have not been a good move to have removed the tar paper, although I can see how it could have happened. In blowing, wind driven weather and the way Hardie siding is fastened and lapped, that may allow rain and most definitely snow to blow through the laps. The tar paper blocked the wind before it was gone.
